# flask: passing parameters across view functions

Tags: python, ajax, flask

How can I pass variables across views in flask

Edit : For illustrative purposes, say I have an variable that is set in user() called id. Of course this is a local variable and is not visible to user_add(). Is there a way to communicate this value with user_add in a nice way preserving the locality?

I have the following code in view:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user():
    ...
    var = setvar()
    ---
    return render_template('users.html')

@app.route('/users/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        var = #somehow get id here
        ---
        return 'user added'
```

I am doing an ajax post to "/user/add"

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    type: "POST"
    url: "/user/add"
    data: data,
    ...
});
```

EDIT: changed ID to var for aesthetics

Comment: Don't overwrite the builtin `id()` function. EDIT: Sorry, meant id.

Comment: I think you mean mean ID! and this is just some sample code not the actual thing im using

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `setid()`? Shouldn't the database generate an `id` for you when you add a user with `user_add()` or is this `id` for some other purpose?

Comment: Well please show the actual code as this is making very little sense.

Comment: this id is for other purposes not databases, thing you're hung up on the ID concept!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am unsure of what the exact use-case is but perhaps have a look at [`Sessions`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions).

You may be able to do something like:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user():
    ...
    session['var'] = setvar()
    ---
    return render_template('users.html')

@app.route('/users/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        var = session['var']
        ---
        return 'user added'
```

Do have a look at the documentation to ensure you are using it correctly. The above is just for illustrating the basic concept.

Comment: This works but this uses the session cookie. Is there a way to pass variables without going through the client?